# How to detect orientation in landscape mode

Tags: java, android, screen-orientation

My program is running in Landscape mode(API7), so I added following commnand in mainfest and my

program.

```
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

and

```
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Althougth in Landscape mode, it also needs to know user is holding in landscape or portrait.

From here, I found some posts about orientation. And I tried

onConfigurationChanged and display.getOrientation();

Unluckly, onConfigurationChanged does not work. And getOrientation() just return Landscape.

How to have the orientation information correctly without SensorManager?

Answer (score 0):

To determine device's current orientation during runtime you can use WindowManager class. The following snippet demonstrate it:

```
WindowManager wm = getWindowManager();
Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

if (d.getWidth() > d.getHeight()) {
// landscape mode
}
else {
// portrait mode
}
```

Comment: I had tried this solution, but it just can return "landscape mode" only

Comment: Try to remove the entries from manifest file regarding screenOrientation and configurationChanges and then use WindowManager. Once you place them you force the device to stay in one mode therfore you have always the same result

Comment: Along with Marcin's remove from manifest you should also remove the setRequestedOrientation from the code. As Marcin stated, with the manifest and code you always have landscape mode. When you test on a device, the landscape layout should always be there even if you are holding the phone in portrait position.

Comment: Even I removed screenOrientation and configurationChanges from manifest, it can't return correctly. I think the problem is coming from the setRequestedOrientation. If using this command, it will lock the orientation and affect the feedback.

Comment: Howard, you are right. So in this case, does it must use SensorManager? Because if I removed setRequestedOrientation, all layout is incorrect.